# What anisotropic method is used for the Gaussian Process RBF kernel?

Tags: scikit-learn

The [scikit-learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html) mention that the `RBF` kernel for gaussian processes has an isotropic variant and an anisotropic variant.  It is pretty clear what is meant by the isotropic variant, since this is the 'basic' version of Gaussian Processes presented in introductory texts.  However, it is not obvious which anisotropic variant is implemented.  Several options are mentioned in passing in [the text by Rasmussen](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf#page=107) (page 89).  Does anyone know which version is implemented in the `sklearn` module `sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF`

Comment: Maybe [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#radial-basis-function-rbf-kernel) and [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#kernels-for-gaussian-processes) can help.

Comment: the formula at this link looks to be for the isotropic variant.  If `l` is a vector, then the division `x_i/l` is not well-defined.  It could be division pointwise, which would make some sense, but this is not a priori obvious.  OTOH, if one were to code this up in `numpy`, then `x_i/l` would be pointwise, and one would not need to do any `if then` logic to account for an anisotropic variant.... This gives me a thing to go look for in the code, at least.  @VivekKumar Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a bit late, but it still may help you or others.
If you take a closer look at the RBF class in \sklearn\gaussian_process\kernel.py, you will find the following description:

```
Parameters
----------
length_scale : float or array with shape (n_features,), default: 1.0
    The length scale of the kernel. If a float, an isotropic kernel is
    used. If an array, an anisotropic kernel is used where each dimension
    of l defines the length-scale of the respective feature dimension.

length_scale_bounds : pair of floats >= 0, default: (1e-5, 1e5)
    The lower and upper bound on length_scale
```

So my assumption is that you need to pass a length_scale array "with the same number of dimensions as the inputs x" (see [scikit - Gaussian Processes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#radial-basis-function-rbf-kernel)). 
To answer the question more precisely about which variant of anisotropy is implemented, my suggestion (without further checking the code) would be that the Euclidean distance is manipulated in the following way (see [Rasmussen](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf#page=107)):

```
r^2(x, x') = (x - x').T * M * (x - x'),
```

where M is a diagonal matrix with the corresponding length scale (actually, 1/l^2) for each direction (in respect to your coordinate system).